# Kafka Streams NPE in MeteredKeyValueStore

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Im trying to run a very basic Stream using the ProcessorAPI in Scala.

```
class KafkaProcessor extends Processor[String, GenericRecord] {
    private var kvStore: KeyValueStore[String, GenericRecord] = _

    override def init(processorContext: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
        this.kvStore = Stores
            .keyValueStoreBuilder(
                Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("random-mame"),
                Serdes.String,
                new GenericAvroSerde
            )
    }

    override def process(
         key: String,
         value: GenericRecord
    ): Unit = {
        val currentState = Option(kvStore.get(key)) // NPE
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems some internal NPE is thrown from the error logs:

```
Exception in thread "test-4294024b-1390-4c2f-ba8e-e520cca728ff-StreamThread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.get(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:134)
at writeside.kafka.AggregateKafkaProcessor.process(KafkaProcessor.scala:64)
at writeside.kafka.AggregateKafkaProcessor.process(KafkaProcessor.scala:35)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:351)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:104)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:413)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:862)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

It is related to the `getTime` inside of the `MeteredKeyValueStore`. Im not sure how this happens and how I can prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a store, you need to declare the store *outside* of the processor (ie, add the store the to `StreamBuilder`), connect the store (via `StreamsBuilder`) to the processor.

Within the processor you use the `ProcessorContext` to get a handle on the store.

See the docs for more details: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html